# CakePHP: form on iframes are blackholed on internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cakephp, iframe, blackhole

I got a weird problem.. all the forms of my cakephp project, are not working properly on an iframe with internet explorer.

I got the security component enabled, so when I submit the form on internet explorer, the blackhole is called. But this only happens when i got my form (or my whole web) inside an iframe. Outside iframe it works on IE, and with firefox or chrome, with iframe, it works ok too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Session.checkAgent` configuration to false.